# Read OTP/SMS in MI device not working (Android)

Tags: android, android-broadcast, android-broadcastreceiver

I have integrated **`Auto read OTP`** in my code and it's working fine except in **MIUI** devices. `BroadcastReceiver` never wake up in case of **MI devices** when `sms` is received. After some efforts I think `MI devices` runs on its `Permission Manager` where all `Permissions` regarding read `sms` are disabled by default as comes in category of `Privacy permissions` and it looks like this : [image]

Now I can't figure out any way to Notify user first to accept or decline the Permission. Device simply disable the permissions by default after app is Installed in device.Is there any way to notify user to Accept the Permission's when app Installed ?

Some code:

**SMSReciever.class** - `BroadcastReceiver` wakes up when SMS is received.

```
public class SMSReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {
private static final String OTP_LENGTH = "6";
private String otp = "";
private IMessageCallback callable;
private static final String TAG = SMSReciever.class.getSimpleName();

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    SmsMessage[] msgs = null;

    if (bundle != null) {

        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {

            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);

            try {
                String sender = msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();

                String phoneNumber = msgs[i].getDisplayOriginatingAddress();
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: phone " + phoneNumber);
                String message = msgs[i].getMessageBody();
                Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: phone " + message);

                otp = GetOtp.extractOTP(message, OTP_LENGTH);

                if (null != sender && message.contains("OTP for AppName") && !TextUtils.isEmpty(otp)) {
                    if (callable != null)
                        callable.getOtp(otp);
                }

            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}

public void setMessageCallable(IMessageCallback callable) {
    this.callable = callable;
}

public interface IMessageCallback {
    void getOtp(String otp);
}
}
```

`AndridManifest.xml` - permissions to receive and read sms

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

MI devices can set permissions as per the App. Can you plz check  if the your app has SMS permission enabled.

You need to go to Settings > Apps > {your_app} > permissions and check if the SMS permission is enabled. As Xiaomi phones provide per app permissions.

Comment: I did attach the screenshot of same in my question, permission are disabled by default but why ? and if disabled how to notify user from app to enable the permission

Comment: Have you tried with giving a priority in Manifest file?

Comment: You can try with this but i am not sure weather it will work or not. I faced this issue with All the MI devices and didn't find the perfect Solution.

<receiver android:name=".SmsListener" >
        <intent-filter android:priority="999" >
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
</receiver>